# Why does my script not work when my input goes past a certain point? Is this a Validation thing?

Tags: javascript, game-development

I'm making a game based on memorization of digits of pi, and when you type out the numbers and get it wrong then there are things that flash red, the correct answer replaces the wrong answer in the input box and the input clears. Everything works fine when the input is below ~ 28-30 but when the input has to start pushing numbers back to make room, the correct answer stops showing up and making it impossible to memorize more than 27 digits, and it should go up to 3,141.

This is what my JavaScript looks like, it's also like my first time with JavaScript and I've had help, but it's not the most efficient, also this isn't all of it, only the stuff that matters. I also have the digits of pi below this but there are so many digits that it shouldn't matter. Is it an HTML or CSS thing and I just don't see it? This is the full code if you want to see all that

https://github.com/42HitchHiker2/Pi-Memorization-Game/tree/main/Pi-Game

I don't know the proper etiquette for this website, so sorry.

(Edit. The code functions in the code snippet, it's still broken but you can see where the problem is.)

(Edit 2. I realized that not everyone knows what 30 digits of pi is so they wouldn't be able to help. it's 3.1415926535897932384626433832 and that's enough that it'll show up as broken)

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input-field")

input.addEventListener("beforeinput", myFunction)

const numbers = "1234567890.".split("")

function myFunction(event) {
    if (event.data && !numbers.includes(event.data)) {
        event.preventDefault()
    } else if (event.data) {
        const charno = input.value.length

    if (pi[charno] != event.data) { 
            input.disabled = true
            event.preventDefault()
            
            function1()

            setTimeout(somethingFunction, 2000)

        }
    }
}


function function1() {input.value += pi[input.value.length]}

function somethingFunction() {  
    input.disabled = false
    input.value = ''

}


const pi = '3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459\
2307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231\
7253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659\
3344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726\
0249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330\
5305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931\
0511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664\
3086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669\
4051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301\
4654958537105079227968925892354201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130\
9960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642\
5223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473\
0359825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778185778053217122680661300\
1927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952\
0353018529689957736225994138912497217752834791315155748572424541506959508295\
3311686172785588907509838175463746493931925506040092770167113900984882401285\
8361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534\
6462080466842590694912933136770289891521047521620569660240580381501935112533\
8243003558764024749647326391419927260426992279678235478163600934172164121992\
4586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955321165\
3449872027559602364806654991198818347977535663698074265425278625518184175746\
7289097777279380008164706001614524919217321721477235014144197356854816136115\
7352552133475741849468438523323907394143334547762416862518983569485562099219\
2221842725502542568876717904946016534668049886272327917860857843838279679766\
8145410095388378636095068006422512520511739298489608412848862694560424196528\
5022210661186306744278622039194945047123713786960956364371917287467764657573\
9624138908658326459958133904780275900994657640789512694683983525957098258226\
2052248940772671947826848260147699090264013639443745530506820349625245174939\
9651431429809190659250937221696461515709858387410597885959772975498930161753\
9284681382686838689427741559918559252459539594310499725246808459872736446958\
4865383673622262609912460805124388439045124413654976278079771569143599770012\
9616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506016842739452267467\
6788952521385225499546667278239864565961163548862305774564980355936345681743\
2411251507606947945109659609402522887971089314566913686722874894056010150330\
8617928680920874760917824938589009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998\
9487226588048575640142704775551323796414515237462343645428584447952658678210\
5114135473573952311342716610213596953623144295248493718711014576540359027993\
4403742007310578539062198387447808478489683321445713868751943506430218453191\
0484810053706146806749192781911979399520614196634287544406437451237181921799\
9839101591956181467514269123974894090718649423196156794520809514655022523160\
3881930142093762137855956638937787083039069792077346722182562599661501421503\
0680384477345492026054146659252014974'
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field">
```

Comment: I entered `3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459` which is a total of 64 digits (including the `3` and `.`). I didn't encounter a problem.

Comment: So to summarize you just need to see more digits in the input field? that is a super simple change perhaps and not really related to script or validation.

Comment: @VLAZ When you got something wrong, Did it show the correct answer?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss But the only solution that I could figure out would be to shrink the text, or to extend the input field, but that's undesirable because of the amount of digits

Comment: Consider perhaps some sort of related element with perhaps a wrap to colorize the "wrong" parts and display/hide that element - kind of like autocompletes do with highlighted text areas to "view what is wrong" vs view it all.